# CSS: Only part of my menu are supposed to hide

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide part of my menu. When I call `display:none` The entire menu disappears. I have id's to separate them so I don't get why this happens. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Categories 1</a>
                <ul id="cat1">
                    <li><a href="#">temp1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">temp2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">temp3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
  background-color: #0000FF;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 15px 0 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font: 12px 'DroidSansBold', Tahoma,sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  box-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
} 

#menu li{
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 120px;
}

#cat1 li{
display: block;
padding: 10px;
}  

#cat1 li a{
background-color: #0000FF;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Somewhat working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfN7t/

Comment: "When I call display:none". When and how are you calling display:none?

Comment: @j08691 Ive tried to call it in #cat1 li and #cat1 li a. When I do the main menu ("Categories 1") disappears also

Comment: @Nilzone- Works fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/ZfN7t/1/

Comment: worked for me as well as @Zenith has it.

Comment: @Zenith I see that. Hmm, it doesn't work in my editor though. but at least that means it's not the code. Thanks for clearing that up. I think you've helped me before as well. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Zenith One more question about this that I'm struggling with: When I hover over my main-menu ("Categories 1"), I want my submeny to be displayed. Ive tried something like this:

#menu li a:hover #cat1 li a{
 color: #dc692e;
    display:block;
}

Any tips? :)

Comment: @Nilzone- You could use `#menu li a:hover + #cat1 li a { display:inline; }`. Here - http://jsfiddle.net/ZfN7t/3/

Comment: @Zenith Last question if you don't mind. When I hover over the main menu - submenu appears. But when i move my mouse away from main, the submenu disappears. I tried to add something like this: ul#cat li a:hover {
    display:inline;
}
to make it possible to go through the submenu as well

Comment: @Nilzone- Here - http://jsfiddle.net/ZfN7t/5/. Note I commented out your margin above as the margin causes the menu to open 120px either side of the menu.

Comment: @Nilzone- No worries man! I won't write it as an answer as it differs from your initial question quite a bit, feel free to check out one of my other answers instead (if you like that is) :)

Comment: @Zenith I know... One more question. Totally fine if you don't want to help anymore! I don't know how to explain so here's video: http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=2wfqs5k&s=5 Why does this happen?
js: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfN7t/9/

Answer (score 0):

When you're dealing with ul inside ul, it's usually easier to style if you give them different classes:

```
<ul id="menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Categories 1</a>
            <ul id="cat1">
                <li class="cat1-item"><a href="#">temp1</a></li>
                <li class="cat1-item"><a href="#">temp2</a></li>
                <li class="cat1-item"><a href="#">temp3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Hide the temp1, temp2, temp3 like this:

```
.menu-item #cat1{
    display:none;
}
```

To display on hover:

```
.menu-item:hover #cat1{
    display:block;
}
```